# Adding Keys to Heroku with Rails 3 and RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, rvm

When attempting the command:

heroku keys:add

I get the following error (I put just the first line of the error):

/home/john/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': no such file to load -- readline (LoadError)

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to recompile Ruby with readline support. Check out this link: [RVM: Ruby Version Manager - 'rvm pkg install readline'](http://beginrescueend.com/packages/readline/)